# What is the need of a physical guru for easy mantras

Tags: mantras, siddhi

Easy mantra in the title refers to the mantra whose pronunciation and other aspects of mantra are easy to comprehend. Such as small bheeja mantra of length varies from one to maximum three characters. Now-a-days the pronunciation and other rules can be obtained or verified from internet.

In this context, as per scriptures, what is the need for a physical guru inorder to get mantra siddi for such mantras?

Is it only because of the reason that it has been mentioned in scriptures that guru is mandatory for any such mantra?

Comment: http://www.arunachala-ramana.org/forum_2/index.php?topic=6564.30  Physical Guru is needed because only a competent Guru can decide whether you are competent for a power of not. Just like to become a doctor or engineer you need to clear exams and prove your worth to your country or world and than alone given the power to construct buildings or operate people, similarly with Siddhis and powers else an incompetent fool can destroy the world of God for their personal gains like Ravana, Hiranayakashyapa and Ashwathama tried in past.

Comment: Mantras are over internet but so are books for becoming doctor, but true degree is given by  an authorized institution to become doctor, Imagine the consequences for a person trying to operate someone reading medical books over the internet. Similarly in the field of spirituality or you need to be blessed by the vision of God itself like Ramkrishna Paramhansa gained siddhis from the Goddess Kali herself.

Comment: Comments should be used for clarification, not make-shift answers or discussion